# Plymouth check gets stuck, preventing service operation

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, plymouth, colors

This is a strange one. If I do, say

```
service jenkins start
```

it will always freeze/get stuck, like waiting for some input. Same is with all services and start/stop commands. However, if I do it like

```
service jenkins start | cat
```

it will work without issues. Also piping to /dev/null works. Using `set -x`, I've managed to track down the freeze at

```
+ '[' -z ']'
+ FANCYTTY=1
+ case "$FANCYTTY" in
+ true
+ /usr/bin/tput xenl
++ /usr/bin/tput cols
+ COLS=144
+ '[' 144 ']'
+ '[' 144 -gt 6 ']'
++ /usr/bin/expr 144 - 7
+ COL=137
+ log_use_plymouth
+ '[' n = y ']'
+ plymouth --ping
```

And indeed, it is always `plymouth --ping` that freezes. It is reproducible directly from shell as well. Any ideas to troubleshoot this?

Ubuntu version is 14.04.01. Plymouth [is supposed to log to /var/log/boot.log](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth), but I don't see anything useful there, just "Stopping" and "Starting" lines that have OK as result.

Process list regards to plymouth looks like this:

```
$ ps -ef | grep plymou
root        478      1  0 Dec01 ?        00:00:04 plymouth-upstart-bridge
root        492      1  0 Dec01 ?        00:00:00 @sbin/plymouthd --mode=boot --attach-to-session
root       1710   1699  0 Dec01 ?        00:00:00 plymouth quit
root       1725   1411  0 Dec01 ?        00:00:00 plymouth --ping
root      48897   2140  0 12:12 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto plymou
```

`strace plymouth --ping` shows this:

```
connect(6, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/org/freedesktop/plymouthd"}, 29) = 0
epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 6, {EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP, {u32=31321216, u64=31321216}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 6, {EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP, {u32=31321216, u64=31321216}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 6, {EPOLLOUT|EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP, {u32=31321216, u64=31321216}}) = 0
epoll_wait(3, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=31321216, u64=31321216}}}, 64, -1) = 1
sendto(6, "P\0", 2, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 2
epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 6, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP, {u32=31321216, u64=31321216}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 6, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP, {u32=31321216, u64=31321216}}) = 0
epoll_wait(3,
```

/var/log/upstart/plymouth.log has one line:

```
error: unexpectedly disconnected from boot status daemon
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, when I was debugging by removing `splash` and `quiet` and replacing them with `plymouth:debug` in /etc/default/grub as adviced in [Plymouth Debugging](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth#Debugging), all my issues seem to be gone. No need to edit logging scripts like above.

It might have been some race condition with plymouth on ubuntu startup which causes plymouth to get stuck. By avoiding splash I am able to avoid the problem.

Before I found that out, I was hacking by editing /lib/lsb/init.functions.d/50-ubuntu-logging to always return 0 for plymouth usage (first function). That didn't help with restart/boot issues though.